# Using # and ## in same statement to represent different levels

Tags: slot, placeholder

I am trying to write some codes to judge if each row of a matrix contains any negative numbers. For example `mat = {{1, 2, 3}, {-1, 2, 3}, {0, 2, 3}}`, and `AnyTrue[mat[[1]], # < 0 &]`, `AnyTrue[mat[[2]], # < 0 &]`, `AnyTrue[mat[[3]], # < 0 &]` will give `False`, `True`, `False` for each of the three rows. Then I prefer to have a shorthand for this, e.g., `AnyTrue[#, ## < 0 &] & /@ mat` will give `{False, True, False}`. The result seems to be correct, but is this shorthand with `#` and `##` in the same statement legitimate? I recall to have seen in Mathematica documentation some time ago using `#` and `##` to represent things of "different levels," but can anyone help me find where this is in the documentation?

Comment: If you are ever unsure what a symbol in Mathematica means, simply select it and press `F1` (or `Cmd + Shift + F` on macOS) - it will open the help page of the associated symbol. In your case, you will get to [`Slot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html) and [`SlotSequence`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SlotSequence.html), which as you can see there have different meanings than you assume

Comment: You can use parentheses to restrict inner pure function: `AnyTrue[#, (# < 0 &)] & /@ mat` or simply use `Negative` as testing function: `AnyTrue[#, Negative] & /@ mat`

Comment: `# != 3 & /@ Total /@ UnitStep@mat`

Comment: After looking at the documentation, it's a good exercise to discover why your code worked by accident and post as a self-answer.

Comment: You can also use the operator forms: `AnyTrue[ Negative] /@ mat` or `AnyTrue[ #<0&] /@ mat`

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation for `Slot`:

> When pure functions are nested, the meaning of slots may become ambiguous, in which case parameters must be specified using an explicit Function construction with named parameters.

So, your nested functions here may or may not work as expected.